# Issue in GET route in asp.net mvc razor c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 routes total in my code.

If I change the position of 1st with 2nd, then 2nd starts to work but 1st gives 404 error.

Am I doing anything wrong in below code?

**This is GET route and works perfectly.**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { 
                    controller = "Category", 
                    action = "Index", 
                    Category = UrlParameter.Optional 
                }
);
```

**This is GET route and always give 404 error.**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default1",
    url: "{Category}",
    defaults: new { 
                    controller = "Product", 
                    action = "Index", 
                    Category = UrlParameter.Optional 
                }
);
```

**This is POST route and works perfectly.**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default_Without_Action",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{Category}",
    defaults: new { 
                    controller = "Product", 
                    action = "GetProducts", 
                    Category = UrlParameter.Optional 
                }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

test if you put url: "{controller}" and see if this works

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default1",
    url: "{controller}",
    defaults: new { 
                    controller = "Product", 
                    action = "Index", 
                    Category = UrlParameter.Optional 
                }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked both routes and working fine.

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


           //Route -1
           routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default1",
           url: "{Category}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", Category = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

           //Route - 2
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                //url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                //defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{Category}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", Category = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

On initial/first request it matches the route-1 and calls the Index Action Method of Product Controller as shown in the picture below. Reason - We defined the defaults parameter for controller Products.

[image]

If we remove the defaults parameter from route 1 then on initial/first request route-2 URL pattern matches and Index Action method of Category Controller will be called, Reason - We defined the defaults parameter for controller Category.

**Browser response with 404 error only when any request doesn't match with the registered URL pattern.**